# Exiting before stack overflow exception

Tags: c#, .net, recursion, stack-overflow

Is there a way in .NET to know in runtime how much stack space is available?

I would like to throw my own defined exception right before stack overflow happens.

Let's say we have some method call inside try/catch. That method leads to unbounded recursion. Now, before the stack overflow happenes the recursion should be stopped and the exception thrown. Exception would say something like: Stopped before stack overflow.

Comment: Hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901185/checking-stack-size-in-c-sharp) helps

Comment: Also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26158/how-does-a-stack-overflow-occur-and-how-do-you-prevent-it

Comment: It occurs to be that it should be relatively simple to add a recursion counter and then throw a custom exception once a threshold was reached.